# Covalent modification of Pyruvate Kinase in RBCs

Tags: molecular-biology, enzymes, hematology

Human body has 4 isozymes of PK and I am particularly interested in the RBC isozyme.
It is capable of being covalently modified through phosphorylation catalysed by Protein Kinase A which is in turn activated by increased cAMP levels in response to Adrenalin or glucagon.
There is evidence of increased cAMP levels in response to adrenalin stimulation in RBCs as seen in this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2269310/
However, this seems counterintuitive because phosphorylation inactivates the enzyme and since glycosis is the sole energy source of RBC's it would deplete it of energy.
Can someone clear this up for me?